# Smooth transition with React Modal

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, react-modal

I am trying to make React modal have a smooth transition when it appears on the screen but can't seem to get the `transition` property to do anything. Right now, the modal pops onto the screen in a jarring manner but I'd like to get it to slowly fade in. Here is my modal with the styles:

```js
const customStyles = {
content: {
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  right: "auto",
  bottom: "auto",
  marginRight: "-50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  transition: "opacity .5s",
  width: "90%",
  maxHeight: "600px",
  overflow: "auto",
  padding: "40px",
  maxWidth: "500px",
  borderRadius: "10px",
  boxShadow: "0px 0px 15px 1px gray",
},
  };


  <Modal
        ariaHideApp={false}
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        style={customStyles}
        contentLabel="Example Modal"
      >
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put opacity as a property itself.

```
const customStyles = {
content: {
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  right: "auto",
  bottom: "auto",
  marginRight: "-50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  opacity: "20%", 
  transition: ".5s",
  width: "90%",
  maxHeight: "600px",
  overflow: "auto",
  padding: "40px",
  maxWidth: "500px",
  borderRadius: "10px",
  boxShadow: "0px 0px 15px 1px gray",
},
  };
```